# New to C++. Question: No operator "=" matches these operands

Tags: c++-cli

I have been using VS for decades. Since it first came out actually.

Using VB.Net and C# ASP.Net, MVC Web and Windows forms. So I know the environment well.

I am just starting to play around with C++ and I have a problem adding constructors to a class.

Here's a code snippet

```
    OleDbConnection _excelconnection;
    OleDbConnection _connection;

    String^ _connstring = "";
    String^ _connectionstring = "";
    String^ _commandtext = "";

    public: DALClass()
    {

    }
    public: DALClass(OleDbConnection connectionin)
    {
        _connection = connectionin;  //<----- No operator "=" matches these operands
        _excelconnection = connectionin; //<------ No operator "=" matches these operands
    }
    public: DALClass(OleDbConnection connectionin, CommandType cmdtypein)
    {
        _connection = connectionin;  //<----- No operator "=" matches these operands
        _excelconnection = connectionin;  //<----- No operator "=" matches these operands
        _cmdtype = cmdtypein;
    }
    public: DALClass(String^ connectionstring)
    {
        _connstring = connectionstring;
        _connection.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
        _excelconnection.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
    }
```

Any clue as to what's causing the No operator "=" matches these operands message? It's the "=" in the  assignments that it's complaining about. The objects either side of the assignment are the same type.
I have tried making the target of the assignment public thinking it may be a scope problem but makes no difference.

Cheers

Comment: `OleDbConnection` probably doesn't have a copy constructor,.

Comment: You need to look closer at the basic syntax of C++/CLI, vis. when to use `a->b` instead of `a.b` and when to use `type^` instead of `type`

Answer (score 2):

This assignment:

```
_connection = connectionin;
```

would **create a copy** of `OleDbConnection` class object (contrary to eg. C#, where it would be a reference type).
Most likely `OleDbConnection`  does not have copy constructor.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection

You may want to use a pointer instead of value type in

```
OleDbConnection _excelconnection;
OleDbConnection _connection;
```

Something like that:

```
OleDbConnection^ _excelconnection;
OleDbConnection^ _connection;
```

However this depends on your usecase as this might generate ownership issues. Your connection object could be destroyed outside of your class, making the pointers invalid.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

Tried that and it tells me:
no suitable conversion function from "OleDbConnection" to "OleDbConnection ^" exists.

Yes. OleDbConnection has no Copy method. But tried using the OleDbConnection.Clone method which exists according to the Object Browser but the compiler reports "OleDbConnection has no member Clone" which is clearly nonsense.

Comment: @RayPooley You are getting this error because you are trying to assign an object type to a pointer to an object type. You need to use '&' to extract the address before assigning to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks again Greg. I have no idea what that means so I guess I have some reading up on pointers to do.

Comment: Sure, no problem. If you come from VB.Net/C# then I would certainly recommend some reading on pointers. Otherwise it will be hard to understand what is happening here.